# Windows App Certification test: testing Windows Store App

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I tested my app in Windows store app certification kit and i got the following error:

```
Crashes and hangs test
PASSED
App launch tests

FAILED
Crashes and hangs
Error Found: The crashes and hangs test detected the following errors:
Application .............._neutral__jarrs3vj594qe was detected by Windows Error Reporting and experienced a crash or hang.
Impact if not fixed: An app that stops responding or crashes can cause data loss and is a poor user experience.
How to fix: Investigate, debug the executable(s) in question to identify and fix the problem, then rebuild and re-test the app. 
Using Application Verifier Within Your Software Development Lifecycle
```

Any ideas what causes this?

Comment: Your app probably caused it

Comment: that was so apt, it was almost hilarious.

Comment: Yes indeed but any sugesstion or on how i can fix this?

Comment: This is why we truly need a StackExchange site for App Store submission questions (for Windows Store as well as Apple's App Store, Google Play, etc.)...questions like this don't quite belong on StackOverflow, but they are valid questions.  Support an App Store site here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54103/app-stores?referrer=stxDSmPYVzhjuiuCuAdO9A2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these [tips for passing Windows certification](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2012/11/12/common-certification-errors-when-submitting-to-the-windows-store.aspx).

There is specific information on the crashes and hangs test at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj657973.aspx#crashes_and_hangs_test.  Read the article, but it suggests these corrective actions:

> Make sure UAC is enabled on the test computer.
>
> Make sure you are running the test on a computer with large enough
>   screen.
>
> If your app fails to launch and your test platform satisfies the
>   prerequisites of ActivateApplication, you can troubleshoot the problem
>   by reviewing the activation event log. To find these entries in the
>   event log:
>   1. Open eventvwr.exe and navigate to the Application and Services Log\Microsoft\Windows\Immersive-Shell folder.
>   2. Filter the view to show Event Ids: 5900-6000.
>   3. Review the log entries for info that might explain why the app didn't launch.

Comment: Using eventvwr.exe i dont see Immersive-Shell folder. There is one WindowsUIImmersive aonge many other in the folder Application and Services Log\Microsoft\Windows